# Why can we connect multiple battries together to get higher voltage or current but not conect multiple DC adapters for the same purpose?

Tags: electric-current, electronics

There are reasons as to why connecting 2 DC sources is a bad idea, but multiple batteries are connected to get higher voltages, like batteries used in inverters, or making Lithium ion battery packs.

Comment: What do you mean by "DC adapter"? A DC adapter is simply meant to change AC to DC. It doesn't make sense to connect two DC adapters in series.

Comment: Also, what you wrote in your question is not the same as what you wrote in your title. Why do you say "connecting 2 DC sources is a bad idea"? In general this is not true. Standard batteries are DC sources, and we can connect them in series to create a larger DC voltage.

Comment: You can connect other DC sources too.  Not just batteries.  It depends on the specifications of the sources if its safe or not.